# Dealing with error catching while working on a puppeteer webscraping project

Tags: node.js, try-catch, puppeteer

im currently working on a webscraping with nodejs and puppeteer and need to overcome error handling
i tried something like this

```
(async () => {
   try{
         content 
   }catch(err){
   content
    }
   content
})();
```

but it didnt work 
then i tried using an anonymous function but i didn't give mi any results either.

```
(async() => {
   (() => {
      content 
   }()catch(err){
      content
   }
   content
})();
```

or with the async keyword

```
(async() => {
   (async() => {
      content 
   }()catch(err){
      content
   }
   content
})();
```

but both of then gave me errors during compilation of program.
Does anyone know a solution to my problem?

Comment: Can you show the error? And update your code, I don't know what are you trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(async () =>{
    console.log(e);
})().catch(err=>{
    console.log("error: " + err);
});
```

Comment: Please add a description to your answer in order the explain the solution

Comment: first u need to declare self invoking async function: 
`(async ()=>{code})()`
which returns promise and on it optional call then() and catch() method to handle errors